# What can I do to install Big Sur without wipe?

Tags: macos, upgrade, beta-seed-program, big-sur

I would like to upgrade to Big Sur on a test system (MacBook Pro (16 inch, 2019)) that already has macOS Catalina 10.15.6 installed.

Since this is to work in a company network, additional software has already been installed:

- Zscaler Security
- Intelligent hub
- McAfee Endpoint Security for Mac

I quit these programs to avoid problems.

In order not to have to do this process again, I would like to perform an in-place upgrade.

`sudo / Applications / Install \ macOS \ Big \ Sur.app/Contents/Resources/startosinstall --agreetolicense --forcequitapps --nointeraction`

With 31% the installation aborts with a meaningless error message. What can I do? Are there logs? Or is wiping and reinstalling faster?

Comment: What exactly is the error message? Did you check whether the mandatory software your company expects already has big sur versions available?

Comment: It is just a test system, I have another production system I use for working. Error is something like an error occured. I do not know where to find better logs. The goal is to identify potential problems of our software. See how it runs on Big Sur.

Comment: Those could *easily* be a result of the software your company has installed. You could build an installer onto a USB key (there is a command available that Apple supports that will do this, gotta google it). Then boot from the USB key and Wipe the drive with disk utility before installing. That might do it unless that software has deep hooks into the system that would prevent a wipe and install. May be time to talk to the IT folks...